# What kinds of pods are tracked in kube_pod_status_ready metric?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-state-metrics

Could I know what kinds of pods are tracked in kube_pod_status_ready metric? Does it contains all control plane concomponents' pod? In my experiment, I can see kube-proxy pod and kube-dns pod and of course the pods I deployed. However, I am not able to see kubelet pod or kube-apiserver pod. Is there any documentation specifying it?

Comment: kubelet and kube-apiserver are system level processes and \`kube\_node\_status\_condition\` can't get these metrics if you want to monitor these metrics you can use something like **node-exporter** or **prometheus-exporter**

Comment: But isn't coredns and kube-proxy system level components/processes? Why they are tracked by kube_node_status_condition? Could you please share some documentations having this kind of information about kube_node_status_condition if you know?